# How to do these matrix operations in GLSL?

Tags: glsl, gpu

In this language

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations

How can I do operations like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone know? The page seems to talk about fixed width like 2x2, 3x3, 4x4, but mine can be much more in dimensions for width.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question right you want to know how to multiplicate matrecies and vectors in glsl.
It's realy easy for example

```
mat4 a;
mat4 b;
vec4 c;
vec4 d = a * b * c;
```

or

```
mat4 a;
mat4 b;
mat4 c = a * b;
```

but keep in mind that matrecies are not commonicative so the order you multiplicate them are important.